# How to export all data from Qlik Sense Desktop app

Tags: qliksense

I’m new to Qlik Sense so, apologies if I’m missing anything that’s painfully obvious.

I downloaded an app that someone at my company created.

My problem is that I want to use that app as a template and update field names and create new visualizations for a demo and I don’t have access to the original data source (the app is no longer actively importing that and I have no idea where that data lives).

When I go to the Data tab there’s a warning that says “Data load failed. Resolve the problems and refresh the data.”

That said, even without the connection, all of the visualizations still work and are interactive so, the data must be in there somewhere(?).

I know it’s possible to export data from a specific visualization by right-clicking it, that’s not what I mean.

I’m looking to get all source data for the entire app. Also, I’m not picky when it comes to format. Multiple CSVs, excel with multiple tabs, sent to external SQL database are all valid options.

Answer (score 1):

Qlik Sense (and View) have something called [Binary Load](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/June2019/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptRegularStatements/Binary.htm). This type of load is loading the data from another `qvf` file.

So in your case:

- create a data (folder) connection to the folder where the source `qvf` file is located
- create new empty app
- open the script editor
- at the top of the script (row 1) type: `Binary lib://MyDataConnection/MyDataFile.qvf;`
- Save and reload

(If the `qvf` file is already in the QS Apps folder then you can simply use: `Binary MyDataFile.qvf;`)

Once the reload is complete your new app will have the same data as the source file (not the same script ... just the data - tables, fields, values)

And at this point you can start manipulating the existing tables/fields (or create new), create visual objects etc.

If you still want to export all the tables you can use the following script to loop through all the tables and export them into `qvd` (for example)

```
for i = 0 to NoOfTables() - 1

  let tableName = TableName($(i));

  Store [$(tableName)] into lib://MyDataConnection\Path\to\some\folder\$(tableName).qvd;
next
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say create a new data (folder) connection? 
Where/how am I creating that connection? 
Is it simply a new folder within Qlik/Sense/Apps/? Do I need to do anything within Qlik Sense to enable the connection?

What do "MyDataConnection" and "MyDataFile.qvf" refer to?
Is "MyDataConnection" simply the directory from which I'd like to take the data?
And is "MyDataFile.qvf" the app name from which I'd like to take the data?

Please keep in mind that I'm completely Qlik Sense illiterate, this is the first I've ever used the app.

Comment: sorry but just now saw your comment. did you manage to get it work?